# Facebook Comment Plugin keeps refreshing and not working on Safari

Tags: javascript, frontend, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments, velo

Our website is a Wix website which has a Facebook Comment Plugin. But recently we found that the FB comment plugin is not working properly on Safari 13. It keeps flickering and refreshing when you try to comment. However it works perfectly on Chrome, FireFox and even old version of Safari like Safari 11. Is there any way to fix it?
The website is:
https://www.sharonpearson.com/gratitude-wall
[image]

Comment: Guess that probably has to do with Safari’s increasingly strict treatment of third-party cookies. The fact that the plugin is not embedded into the main document directly, but inside of an iframe that itself loads from the different domain `www-sharonpearson-com.filesusr.com` could probably add to the “usual” issues you can expect in that regard. I’d first of all try and see if it behaves differently in Safari, if you call that document directly, outside of the parent page.